# Magento 2 less compilation error while setup:static-content:deploy

Tags: magento-2.1, less, less-css

After updating to Magento 2.1.16 on my staging server with nginx server and php7.0 I am facing issue in compiling less and css files.
The files `styles-l.css` and `styles-m.css` are missing - not generated.

During static contend deploy I get errors:

> Compilation from source: /srv/www/rmstaging/public_html/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/styles-l.less
>
> Compilation from source:
> frontend/Smartwave/porto_rtl/en_US/css/styles-l.less
> variable @modal-popup-breakpoint-screen__m is undefined in file /srv/www/rmstaging/public_html/var/view_preprocessed/css/frontend/Smartwave/porto_rtl/en_US/Magento_Checkout/css/source/module/checkout/_tooltip.less in _tooltip.less on line 11, column 41

I tried many solution including on given in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50764127/magento-2-less-compilation-error-while-setupstatic-contentdeploy-and-frontend  given by @Ashsih Raj. But did not work either.

I had the same issue on localhost but that was fixed mysteriously. I think the only change is that on my localhost I compiles using PHP7.1

Please advise.

Comment: You can delete this file if it is not necessary

Comment: Which file should be deleted?

Comment: Delete file .less you have the error

Comment: @VuTranKien Did that already but no use.

Answer (score 20):

For all Porto Theme users upgrading to Magento 2.3:

Edit the following files (also other language codes if available):

```
app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Magento_Checkout/web/css/source/module/checkout/_tooltip.less
app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto_rtl/Magento_Checkout/web/css/source/module/checkout/_tooltip.less
```

Replace the following piece of code, found on line 11:

```
@checkout-tooltip-breakpoint__screen-m: @modal-popup-breakpoint-screen__m;
```

with the following code:

```
@checkout-tooltip-breakpoint__screen-m: @screen__m;
```

Diff

```
11c11
< @checkout-tooltip-breakpoint__screen-m: @modal-popup-breakpoint-screen__m;
---
> @checkout-tooltip-breakpoint__screen-m: @screen__m;
```

Please note: In current versions of the Porto Theme there is a Patch included for Magento 2.3!

Comment: the correct line is like in the diff: `@checkout-tooltip-breakpoint__screen-m: @screen__m;`

We had the en_GB version,so the error code if anyone is wondering was: `report.ERROR: variable @modal-popup-breakpoint-screen__m is undefined in file [...]/var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto/en_GB/Magento_Checkout/css/source/module/checkout/_tooltip.less in _tooltip.less on line 11, column 41`

Comment: **Please note: In current versions of the Porto Theme there is a Patch included for Magento 2.3!** that was the most important for my **Magento v.2.3.1** installation.

Comment: After applying the patch, also delete the var/view_processed folder before retrying the deploy.

Answer (score 5):

**Update:**

This is not a permanent fix, but to get your website back up & running,

/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Magento_Checkout/web/css/source/module/checkout

Rename _tooltip.less to _tooltip.less-removed

Remember to clear your cached files & redeploy:

```
rm -rf pub/static/*; rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/*; php -f bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Answer (score 3):

Same issue here with magento version 2.3.1

It is Always Porto theme breaking my sites.

My advice Porto Theme there is a Patch included for Magento.
The file is called Patch for Magento 2.3.x.zip
This will resolve your issues. Apply this patch please and after this you should be fine again.

**Step 1** download the latest Porto magento 2 theme package.

**Step 2** unpack/extract all files and folders

**Step 3** unpack/extract all files from the `\Theme Files\Magento 2.x\Patch` for Magento 2.3.1 And Above.zip if you not have done this yet **and the one that resolves your issues `\Theme Files\Magento 2.x\Patch for Magento 2.3.x.zip`

Upload the folder app from both patches (or the ones you did not applied) with Filezilla (or any ftp program you use) to your public_html folder or whatever magento installation folder you use.

**Problem solved.**

New problem from Porto Theme:
Check your front end categories. Mine are not working any more after updating Porto theme but this is another issue i am working on.

Answer (score 1):

Define `@modal-popup-breakpoint-screen__m` in your theme. Here is the location:
`Magento_Checkout/css/source/module/checkout/_tooltip.less`

[Here is the example how you define](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3/app/design/frontend/Magento/luma/Magento_Theme/web/css/source/_module.less#L27)

Comment: tried this but did not work. I see the files **css/styles-l.css** and **css/styles-m.css** are still missing.

Comment: I think you missing your less file where define all constant. Make sure that you have all less file otherwise you can't proceed with it.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I already did it and it worked a bit. But there were other sections of the theme which were broken.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I already did it and it worked a bit. But there were other sections of the theme which were broken. Finally, after spending some more issue, I found that after upgrade to Magento 2.1.16 somehow the theme fallback is not working.
I am using custom theme -> child of Smartwave Porto theme -> child of Magento Blank. When doing static_content deploy, the CSS from porto is not loaded especially for Checkout module. I copied the files from porto to custom theme and it worked. BUT I DON'T THINK IT IS PROPER SOLUTION. AND ONE MORE THING THE WHOLE THING IS WORKING FINE ON LCLHST

Comment: I just copied files from parent theme SmartWave Porto to My Child theme and things worked. But I need more robust solution.

Comment: I am facing same issue : https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/322669/85990

Answer (score 0):

For myself, I was getting:

> Compilation from source: vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/styles-m.less
> Unable to get content for 'frontend/Magento/blank/en_AU/css/source/components/_modals.less'

## Quick Fix

I found removing the vendor then re-installing:

```
rm -rf vendor/
composer -n install
```

Immediately solved the issue when running `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`, but then it would fail once again after the first deploy.

## Permanent Fix

Searching for this file in vendor helped me

```
find . -type f -name "_modals.less" | grep -i "source/components"

./vendor/magento/magento2-base/lib/web/css/source/components/_modals.less
./lib/web/css/source/components/_modals.less
```

*These 2 files were identical for me*

**Copying one of these files into my theme directory resolved these for future deploys:**

```
mkdir -p ./app/design/frontend/<MY_VENDOR>/<MY_THEME>/web/css/source/components
cp  ./vendor/magento/magento2-base/lib/web/css/source/components/_modals.less ./app/design/frontend/<MY_VENDOR>/<MY_THEME>/web/css/source/components/_modals.less
```