# Error while running static deploy command in magento 2

Tags: magento2.3.3, static-content-deploy, less-compilation

I am getting the error again & again, though I have removed/var/pub & pub/static/frontend Error while running static deploy command in Magento

Comment: This is the most explicit error message I saw in my life. I don't know what more could you expect?

Comment: why you gave -ive vote, please give me solution

Comment: see this you may get help https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/264154/78648

Comment: You are using an undefined variable in one of your less files the error clearly states it. pub/static files are generated from module and theme files (where the error is introduced). removing files from pub/static won't do you any good. You have to find your less file in your modules or theme and remove the line of code that uses an undefined variable. You also have to remove var/view_preprocessed (also written in the error message)

Answer (score 2):

`@mobile-cart-padding` is need to defined at your variable.less or _extends.less files at your theme folder.

After that, you need to do static content deploy

Comment: thanks @amit bera