# Magento 2.3.4 magento blank and luma theme less compilation error

Tags: magento2, php-7.2

After updating to **Magento 2.3.4 from 2.2.6** on my staging server with **nginx server and php7.2** I am facing issue in **compiling less and css files**. The files **styles-l.css and styles-m.css** are missing - not generated.

During static contend deploy I get errors:
Compilation from source:

```
vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/styles-l.less
variable @modal-popup-breakpoint-screen__m is undefined in file var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/frontend/Magento/blank/en_US/Magento_Checkout/css/source/module/checkout/_tooltip.less in _tooltip.less on line 11, column 41
09| 
10| @checkout-tooltip__hover__z-index: @tooltip__z-index;
11| @checkout-tooltip-breakpoint__screen-m: @modal-popup-breakpoint-screen__m;
12| 
13| @checkout-tooltip-icon-arrow__font-size: 10px;
14| @checkout-tooltip-icon-arrow__left: -( @checkout-tooltip-content__padding + @checkout-tooltip-icon-arrow__font-size - @checkout-tooltip-content__border-width);
```

tried this but not fixed
[Magento 2 less compilation error while setup:static-content:deploy](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/252894/magento-2-less-compilation-error-while-setupstatic-contentdeploy)

remove **pub/static/adminhtml, pub/static/frontent, var/view_preprocessed**. After that, deploy your Magento again via SSH and check your site again.