# Static content deploy error after upgrading magento 2.3.3 to 2.3.5 (EE)

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento-enterprise, upgrade, setup-upgrade

I am facing Compilation from source: LESS file is an empty issue after Magento upgrade from 2.3.3 to 2.3.5 EE at the time of Static content deploy.

Anyone face OR fixed such kind of issues??

[image]?

Comment: Please check your file is empty or not - First and if not try to clear pub/static generate var/cache and var/view_process* and re deploy might solve issue

Comment: @NileshDubey I tried these things but no luck any idea?

Comment: Sorry I have no more to say but please try this one might help you - https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/317576/77554

Comment: @NileshDubey Thanks buddy no problem, link mentioned by you already tried no luck.

Comment: @NileshDubey Its fixed by removing empty css

Comment: Great Job - really happy that you have resolved it

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue by removing blank/empty css from mentioned path.